# Ruby: Trying to understand why my code works perfectly sometimes, but then is stuck in a loop other times

Tags: ruby, oop, loops, random, multidimensional-array

So I'm going through extra prep-work material for App Academy's bootcamp, and one of the example problems is to create a method, swingers, that takes an argument of an array of couples and return a similar array with the couples mixed up.

The argument's format is such: ([[male,female],[male,female]..])

My issue is that most of the time I execute the code, I receive the correct output.
However, sometimes the code does not execute and gets stuck in a loop(I'm assuming)

I'm sure I haven't written the best code, maybe there is something I can change to stop this issue.

Here is my code:

```
def swingers(couples)
    new_couples = []
    target_size = couples.size
    i = 0 

    males   = couples.each_with_object([]) {|(male,female),arr| arr << male}
    females = couples.each_with_object([]) {|(male,female),arr| arr << female}

    until new_couples.size == target_size
        while true
            current_male   = males[rand(0..males.size-1)]
            current_female = females[rand(0..females.size-1)]

            if !couples.include?([current_male,current_female])
                break
            end
        end

        males.delete(current_male)
        females.delete(current_female)

        new_couples[i] = [current_male, current_female]
        i += 1
    end
    new_couples
end

p swingers([
  ["Clyde", "Bonnie"],
  ["Paris", "Helen"],
  ["Romeo", "Juliet"]
])
```

When I press ctrl+c (I'm running command line from Windows), the error I receive states:

> swingers.rb:14:in `include?': Interrupt
>           from swingers.rb:14:in`swingers'
>           from swingers.rb:32:in `'

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @meagar arrays don't have `keys` method, you should use `map`: `couples.map { |v| v[0] }.zip(couples.map { |v| v[1] }.shuffle)`

Comment: @mdesantis That's long since been addressed, reload the page

Answer (score 1):

You wind up looping forever, because of this test:

```
        if !couples.include?([current_male,current_female])
            break
        end
```

It's possible for the final two couples to be paired up with their original partners, in which case the `break` can never be reached.

For example, given your inputs

```
["Clyde", "Bonnie"],
["Paris", "Helen"],
["Romeo", "Juliet"]
```

If your first pair is Clyde and Helen, and your second pair is Paris and Bonnie, that leaves only Romeo and Juliet left to pair up. Your loop will test whether `['Romeo', 'Juliet']` exists inside you original `couples` array, and they do, so it will try to generate a new pairing, but there are only one male an one female left, so it will never escape your `while true`.

A few notes more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

1. Don't do this:

   ```
   males   = couples.each_with_object([]) {|(male,female),arr| arr << male}
   ```

   Do do this:

   ```
   males = couples.map(&:first)
   ```
2. Don't do this:

   ```
   current_male   = males[rand(0..males.size-1)]
   ```

   Do do this:

   ```
   current_male = males.sample
   ```

A slightly more naive (but shorter and guaranteed to complete, assuming at least two pairs are given as inputs) method. This generates a complete new set of pairings, and *then* tests whether any any of the new pairs exists in the original set of pairs.

```
def swingers(pairs)
  while true
    new_pairs = pairs.map(&:first).zip(pairs.map(&:last).shuffle)
    return new_pairs unless new_pairs.any? { |pair| pairs.include? pair }
  end
end
```

Comment: awesome!! thanks so much! 
I'm fairly new to programming and I understand that part of coding also requires your code to be readable, would your code count as such?

I'm definitely going to look into the use of the ampersand in an argument and the zip method as well.

Comment: My code, the last sample, is *extremely* readable to experienced Rubyists.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the last couple ends up with the original partners, so the loop loops endlessly.

Some methods may simplify your code. Have a look at [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-transpose). Also, you might want to rethink your algorithm: `loop until it fits` is prone to this kind of errors and you can not predict how much time it 's going to take.

Suppose you rotate the females array a random number of positions ([Array#rotate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-rotate)) and zip the two lists for exciting new pairings ([Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-zip)).

Comment: thanks for the input!
I just looked up the transpose method on Ruby's API and tried it out on irb but it didn't really return what I was expecting..
I'll try to figure it out more later.

Instead of using the "loop until it fits", what are some best-practice methods/loops you would suggest?